# copy rows from one table to another MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have two tables exactly the same in structure.

**product_test1, product_test2**

Rows with a single product_test2 table are added with a single id_product that is not repeated even in the product_test1 table because it is a table that does not receive data until I update it with the product_test2 table, and neither in the product_test2 table since it is a unique ID.

I am using WorkBench. I want to incorporate all the new rows that have come into the product_test2 table into the product_test1 table. I just want to add those rows but not update records that are already inserted in product_test1 before. In short, just add the new rows that enter the product_test2 table to the product_test1 table.

I am using an algorithm that gives me an error, I would like to know what the error is and if it can be done in a simpler way without having to put the names of all the columns, but above all, to know why it gives me an error.

**The error is: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'product_test1.product_id' in 'where clause'**

The code is:

```
INSERT INTO `product_test1`


(product_id,
product_name,
product_image, 
brand_id, 
categories_id......)

SELECT product_id, 
product_name, 
product_image, 
brand_id, 
categories_id.... 


FROM `product_test2` WHERE `product_test1.product_id` <> `product_test2.product_id
```

With the <> command I want the table to be traversed and find only the different or mismatched id_products between the product_test1 table and the product_test2 table

Answer (score 0):

You can try a **trigger** to insert to table1 after the insertion of table2 is completed.

```
Create Trigger insert_to_product_test1
 ON product_test2 
 AFTER INSERT
AS
  DECLARE 
       @product_id int,
       @product_name varchar,
       @product_image varchar,
       @brand_id int,
       @categories_id int
    
       SELECT @product_id = ins.product_id  FROM inserted ins;
       SELECT @product_name = ins.product_name  FROM inserted ins;
       SELECT @product_image = ins.product_image  FROM inserted ins;
       SELECT @brand_id = ins.brand_id  FROM inserted ins;
       SELECT @categories_id = ins.categories_id   FROM inserted ins;
    
If ( SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM product_test1  WHERE product_id =  @product_id) =0
         BEGIN
           INSERT INTO product_test1(product_id,product_name,product_image, 
           brand_id,categories_id......) 
           VALUES(@product_id,@product_name,@product_image 
          ,@brand_id ,@categories_id ...)
END
```